# Any performance trick for drawing hundreds of images on an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have hundreds of images i need to draw on an HTML5 canvas, which arrive in realtime - and today i'm drawing them all in a for loop using the drawImage API.

these images arrive in groups, each group contains 100-200 images.
All the images from the same group should be drawn exactly at the same time.

Is there some API i can use to "pause" rendering, draw all the images, and then "resume" the rendering again?

I looked at the canvas HTML5 official API but couldn't find something suitable.

Thanks alot!

Amit

Edit:
In ther words, i'm looking for a way to tell the canvas / browser something like this: "Hey, I'm going to draw a bunch of images, don't bother handling them one by one, i'll tell you once i'm finished"

Comment: I'm not sure I get totally what you're after, but you could use off-screen canvases, draw each group on one off-screen canvas, then only draw said canvases to the main one.

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches to optimise speed. My thought would be to combine them: You can render everything off-screen, which has the effect of you not seeing the rendering. You can then use multiple transparent canvas as layers. So you then shift the off-screen canvas on top of the original one, like you can do with any other DOM element.

Have a look [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-canvashtml5layering/).

Comment: Good plan! - Upvote. BTW, You don't have to add the new buffer canvas to the DOM -- you can just keep it in-memory-only.  To add to your answer: 1. Create an in-memory buffering canvas with `var bufferCanvas = document.createElement...` 2. Load one "group" of images in a batch. 3. Draw them on the buffer canvas. 4. When all the group's images are drawn you can draw the buffer canvas to the visible canvas with `mainContext.drawImage(bufferCanvas,0,0)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to be more clear regarding my question... It's not the i'm concerned about what images will be visible during the loop, because it starts and ends within 0-30 msec. I'm interested in bringing this duration to minimum. I've tried drawing the same images on a canvas with style.visibility hidden and it didn't improve the situation.